# Javascript files in django have 404 error on Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I think my javascript files are somehow not being read by Chrome. In the "Network" section of the developer tools (inspect) in Chrome, my js file has a status 404 and is colored red. The below script is the code in my html file:

```
<script src="js/checkout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The src path is correct, because vscode shows me the correct js file when I click the `src=js/checkout.js` of the script tag. I removed all cache from the browser, but the problem still persists. I hope you can guys can help me, and please leave a question if you have one.

Comment: you have to use `{% static 'js/checkout.js' %}` this will get relative path inside static folder and if you don't want to use `{% static '' %}` than you've to specify relative path somthing like this i assume your html document is inside templates ``../static/js/checkout.js``

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but  it still doesn't work when I put it in.

Comment: as I remember you have to put static files in folder `static` and use urls like `/static/js/checkout.js`. Other problem can be if you run without `debug mode` because it needs to use web server like `Apache`,`Nginx` to server static files.

Comment: btw: `vscode` shows only that it is correct local path but it has nothing to do with correct URLS.

Comment: Hello @codebuilder can you provide your full html template and static conf.

Comment: Hey, I was actually working on the static files, and now it seems to work. I guess I had to connect the js file to my static file.